# what does `_` mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across the following code:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});
```

What does `_` mean in the above code? I tried replacing `_` with `null` but it is saying syntax error. However `undefined` would work. I am new to Javascript. So any comments would appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It's an arbitrary variable name, one that isn't being used in the anonymous function despite being passed, and available, to it. Did you try `console.log(_)` within the function?

Comment: Thanks @MrTux. The other article was very helpful. It's simply a parameter to be ignored in a function. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a regular variable. In some languages, like F#, it means that this argument is not intended to be used. For example, see [F#'s underscore: why not just create a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105422/fs-underscore-why-not-just-create-a-variable-name)

Comment: Yep. `_` is often used as a golfcoding narcissistic way to say *"I know what this argument slot represents but I don't use it in my function body"* - even if does not differs in using `val`, `v`, `key`, `k` etc (the same way `i` *shortcodes* for *index*) which are more bro-I-see-you-friendly